# Authorized connection to mongoDB in Haskell

Tags: mongodb, haskell

How to authenticate to mongoDB?

I am using this driver http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mongoDB

I can't find anything related in the docs or source.

Comment: downvoter: Care to exaplain? Perhaps, if I overlooked something obvious, you could enlighten me.

Comment: What's your question? Presumably you are trying to use that driver to connect to a mongoDB server, but you are hitting problems. What are those problems? What have you tried? What error messages did you get? At compile-time or run-time? Etc.

Comment: @dave4420 the question looks clear for me: how to authenticate to mongoDB.

Comment: 1. I see, next time I will try to word my question better. 2. NVM, Yuras is right.

Comment: @Yuras I congratulate you on your question-decoding skills. But I couldn't understand the question. Presumably the five people (I'm not one of them, btw) who downvoted the question couldn't understand it either. The person who voted to close indicated it was because it was *"not a real question: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here."*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [auth](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mongoDB/1.3.2/doc/html/Database-MongoDB-Query.html#v%3aauth) function. From the docs:

> ```
> auth :: MonadIO' m => Username -> Password -> Action m Bool
> ```
>
> Authenticate with the current database (if server is running in secure mode). Return whether authentication was successful or not. Reauthentication is required for every new pipe.